# Delegate Methods Not Firing on Search Results Table

Tags: ios5, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

All,

I have a UITableView w/detail, with a Search bar, created from code. Works fine on selected items except it doesn't work when an item is clicked from the search results; no delegate methods fire. Never seen this type of behavior before so I don't know where the issue lies.

I get the same behavior with standard table cells as well as custom table cells.

Appreciate any guidance on this and thanks.

**Just Hangs Here**
[image]

```
//ViewController.h
 @interface SongsViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate>
{
   NSMutableArray *searchData;
   UISearchBar *searchBar;
   UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
   UITableViewCell *customSongCell;
 }




 //ViewController.m
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 88)];

   [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
   [searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Title",@"Style", nil]];

   searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
   searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
   searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; 

   //Load custom table cell
    UINib *songCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SongItem" bundle:nil];

  //Register this nib, which contains the cell
  [[self tableView] registerNib:songCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SongItemCell"];

  // create a filtered list that will contain products for the search results table.
  SongStore *ps = [SongStore defaultStore];
  NSArray *songObjects = [ps allSongs];

  self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [songObjects count]];
  self.masterSongArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[ps allSongs]];

 [self refreshData];

 [self.tableView reloadData];
 self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue. I forgot to set this searchDisplayController delegates:

`[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];`

So make sure you set **All** of these:

```
searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
[searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
```